# How to handle large mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, analytics, sharding

We have a collection that is potentially going to be very large.This collection used to store Bill releated data. So this is often used to reporting/Analytics purpose.

Please let me know the best approch to handle this large collection

1) Can I split and archive the old data(say 12 months period)?.But here old data is required to get analytic reports.I want to query this old data to show the sale comparion for past 2 yesrs.

2)can I have new collection with old data(12 months) .So for every 12 months i've to create new collection. For reports generation,I've to access all this documents to query. So this will cause performance problem?

3) Can I go for Sharding?

Answer (score 2):

There are many variables to account for, the clearest being what hardware you use, how the data is structured, and how it is queried. A distributed network ought to be able to chew through your data faster than a single machine, but before diving into that solution I recommend generating an absurd amount of mock data comparable to what you are expecting, and then testing various approaches. Seriously. Create a bunch of data, and try to break things. It's fun! Soon enough you'll know more about what your problem requires than any website could tell you.

As for direct responses:

1. Perhaps, before archiving the data, appropriate stats summaries can be generated (or updated). Those summaries/simplifications can be used for sale comparisons without reloading all of the archived data they represent.
2. This strikes me as sensible. By splitting up the sales data, you have more control over how much data needs to be accessed. After all, a user won't always wish to see 3 years of data, they may only wish to see last week's.
3. Move to sharding when you actually need it. As is stated on the MongoDB site:

   > Converting an unsharded database to a sharded cluster is easy and seamless, so there is little advantage in configuring sharding while your data set is small.

You'll know it's time when your memory-map approaches the server's RAM limit. MongoDB supports reading and writing to databases too large to keep in memory, but I'm sure you already know that is *SLOW*.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. As you stated in point no 1 "appropriate stats summaries can be generated",could you please elaborate on this point. How can I make summary If i required old data to compare with new year data? Is it possible in summary?

Comment: That would depend on your data and what kind of comparisons you wish to make. For example, anything beyond 12 months could be simplified to weekly sums. Or, perhaps a common stat your users look up is daily sales totals. Instead of adding up the totals from every sale record, a per day total can be pre-calculated and kept on hand.

Comment: Thank you. Where I can store Pre-calculation summary? In a diffrent collection? Can you please enlighten on this..

Comment: Correct. The summaries would be made accessible in a new collection while the raw data is archived.

Comment: To be clear, my numbered list was designed to correspond with your numbered list. So the points I made in `2.` were in response to your `2)`